# How to split an array of objects into multiple sub arrays of a given size

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like to split an array of objects into multiple array that hold no more than 10 elements.

Spent quite a while looking at examples, and the closest I can find is in C#:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select((Value, Index) => new {Value, Index})
    .GroupBy(p => p.Index/10)
    .Select(g => g.Select(p => p.Value).ToList())
```

This runs and works in LinqPad, so I tried to convert it to VB.Net:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(Function(Value, Index) New With {Value, Index}) _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index / 10) _
    .Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(p) p.Value).ToList())
```

But this doesn't give the same result, even though it looks like it should.

Obviously this is just an example and I would really like it to work on an array of customs objects. (Bonus points: why aren't these two examples equivalent?).

Comment: `But this doesn't give the same result`: then: what *does* it give? Wherein does it differ? My guess (been a long time since VB): the division results in doubles instead of integers?

Comment: The results are quite big, so I didn't include them to avoid clutter... it gives a hundred arrays with one item in each,

Comment: If you'd have taken a look at the group-key you should've seen (judging from the currently posted answers which support my hunch) that the keys are all doubles / floats instead of integers. Debugging and looking at the actual results comparing them to expected results should've saved you from posting this question ;-)

Comment: how would you look at the group-key, I'm new to linq, also, how can you debug linq? I haven't worked this out yet... its more of a run it and find out method. which isn't great... what is your suggestion?

Comment: The `.Select(...)` after the `GroupBy()` "strips" the keys from the GroupBy result so probably the easiest would be storing the intermediate results in a variable and first looking at that (like `foo = Enumerable....GroupBy(...)`, then inspect `foo` with the debugger).

Comment: ah, ok, so break it down into multiple statements.

Comment: That would've been easiest for a beginner I guess; not sure if there's a simpler/better way (especially in VB.net). But debugging 101 is, indeed, simplify, simplify, simplify. Break stuff in simpler/smaller/easier to understand pieces until you understand ;-) That is exactly why I posted my/the first comment here; read it again ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# you have integer division which means that the decimal places are truncated and the result is also an `int`. That's why it works in C# and not in VB.NET which maintains decimal places since it converts it to `Double`.

If you want to have the same behaviour in VB.NET you need to use `\` instead of `/`.

See: [\ Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx)

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(Function(Value, Index) New With {Value, Index}) _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index \ 10) _
    .Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(p) p.Value).ToList())
```

Answer (score -1):

Other wise try the below

```
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int maxArrayLimit = 10;

        //Total values 0-103
        List<int> lstNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 103).Select(x => x).ToList<int>();

        //to hold splited values 
        List<List<int>> lstSplitedNumbers = new List<List<int>>();

        while (currentPosition < lstNumbers.Count)
        {
            //spliting values based on currentPosition to maxArrayLimit
            List<int> lstCurrentNumbers = lstNumbers.Skip(currentPosition).Take(maxArrayLimit).ToList<int>();
            lstSplitedNumbers.Add(lstCurrentNumbers);
            //rest the current position
            currentPosition += lstCurrentNumbers.Count;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a linq example.